# Titanium Desktop - Get Menubar icon Position

Tags: javascript, titanium, menubar, tray

I am trying to create an app where the main window is shown only when the menubar icon is clicked. I have create the menubar icon but I can't figure out how to position the window underneath it. Is there a way to get the its x position?

This is my javascript for the menubar icon:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.getCurrentWindow();

var tray = Titanium.UI.addTray(
    "app://images/menubar.png",
    function(){ win.show(); }
);
```

This shows the window when the menubar icon is clicked, but it shows up in the center of the screen.